# rollback a video when its container is hidden

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

So far, i can pause the video, but not rollback it to the beginning (so that it start from 0 next time).

```
<video id="video" src="videos/movie.ogg" type='video/ogg' controls='controls'>
  Your brwoser doesn't seems to support video
</video>
```

jQuery code:

```
  $('#video')[0].pause();//Pause video
```

Ok, it's paused, but obviously, next time i will get the video run from where it got paused. I need to rollback the video and put it at its initial state (at the 0 seconds).

Is there any way to do that? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be

```
$('#video')[0].currentTime = 0;
```

[W3C current Time doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/media-elements.html#dom-media-currenttime)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the currentTime method.

```
$('#video')[0].currentTime = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the [load method](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/media-elements.html#dom-media-load). In case of a normal video without a poster pauseing and setting the currentTime to 0 might be ok, at least if you have a poster attribute, it won't help.

The load method let's the browser restart it's player based on the current markup of the video and it's source/track childs. In case the attributes didn't change since then, it will create a real and full rollback to the initial state of the video.

```
$('video').get(0).load();
//in case you are using a autoplay attribute for the first time, but don't want have it after your rollback, do the following
$('video').eq(0).prop('autoplay', false).get(0).load();
```